# mismath.sty bug?

Tags: math-mode, packages, mathtools

With the `mismath.sty` package loaded, the following source causes error:

```
./mismath_paired_delim_bug.tex:14: Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \futurelet 
l.14 $\eqclass{0}
                 $
```

Without the `mismath` package, the source compiles OK.

**Where is the bug in `mismath`?**

(Yes, I realize I don't actually use `mismath` functionality in this source, but it is merely a MWE to illustrate the issue. In my actual document, I *do* use `mismath` functionality.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{mismath}    % CAUSES ERROR

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\eqclass}{\lbrack}{\rbrack}
\newcommand{\muspace}{\mspace{1mu}}
\newcommand{\eqclasssim}[1]{\eqclass{#1}_{{}\muspace\muspace\muspace\raisebox{-1pt}{$\scriptstyle\sim$}}}

\begin{document}

$\eqclass{0}$

$\eqclasssim{0}$

\end{document}

Package: amsmath 2022/04/08 v2.17n AMS math features
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
Package: mathtools 2022/06/29 v1.29 mathematical typesetting tools
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
Package: mhsetup 2021/03/18 v1.4 programming setup (MH)
Package: mismath 2022/12/26 v2.1 .dtx mismath file
Package: esvect 
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
Package: xspace 2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
Package: ibrackets 2022/12/26 v1.1 .dtx ibrackets file
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
```

**Added:** The following causes essentially the same error, and for the same reason, namely, that `mismath` now breaks things when it loads `ibrackets:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\setimage}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1}
```

Comment: I not see any mistakes. It compiles perfectly with mismath package.

Comment: Or you choose `\usepackage{amsmath}` or the robust `\usepackage{mathtools}`. How you compile? You use Overleaf or other?

Comment: the package loads ibrackets which makes the brackets active and this explodes. Write to the author.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Why for me it compiles perfectly?

Comment: @Sebastiano: I just tried it again, with same error. That is even working directly from the command line!

Comment: I"m using TeXLive 2022, with all packages updated using TeXLive Utility, under macOS Ventura. Most peculiar it works for some but not others. Different versions of basic LaTeX packages or of mismath??

Comment: @Sebastiano: I suspect that you are not using most recent version of `mismath`, which includes loading the `ibrackets` package identified by Ulrike Fischer as causing the difficulty.

Comment: @murray It is true. I have done an upload now. The package mismath is the 12/28/2022 and I had the old version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for this bug report. I posted today a new release of `mismath` in which `ibrackets` is now just an option that loads the corresponding package. So one can choose if he wants to be perverse or not :-)

Indeed there was an incompatibility with square brackets used inside `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`. Nevertheless, using the macro
`\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\setimage}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1}`
as mentioned above, doesn't produce an error in my tests.

Comment: Thank you for the quick update!

Comment: The fixed `mismath` version 2.2, dated 6 January 2023, today reached the CTAN mirror from which TeXLive Utility retrieve it in an update.

Answer (score 10):

The [`mismath` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mismath) has been recently updated to load `ibrackets` which should help in typesetting the perverse<sup>1</sup> French notation for intervals.

```
% \changes{v2.1}{2022/12/26}{
%     - Improved management of square brackets with the ibrackets package,
%     - new macros codim, sinc, var, eqdef*,
%     - removing the systematic warning for paren command
%     - a small change in norm command -> bars in small size
%     - several changes in documentation}
```

In the meantime, it breaks legal uses of `[` and `]` such as in the case of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

File a complaint to the author of `mismath` who should at least provide an option for nonperverse mathematicians to *not* load `ibrackets`.

In the meantime, redefine `\lbrack` and `\rbrack` in a way that fools `ibrackets`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{mismath}

\let\lbrack\relax \let\rbrack\relax
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrack}{\mathopen} {operators}{"5B}{largesymbols}{"02}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrack}{\mathclose}{operators}{"5D}{largesymbols}{"03}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\eqclass}{\lbrack}{\rbrack}
\newcommand{\eqclasssim}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{$\eqclass{#1}$}%
  \eqclass{#1}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp0+\depth}{%
    $\mathsurround=0pt\scriptstyle\mspace{2mu}\sim$%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

$\eqclass{0}$

$\eqclasssim{0}$

\end{document}
```

I added a different definition of your `\eqclassim` command that works across font size changes.

[image]

**Footnote**

<sup>1</sup> From the TeXbook: **Exercise 18.14** Some perverse mathematicians use brackets backwards,
to denote “open intervals.”

Comment: +1, especially for the footnote.

Comment: The trouble with *not* using brackets for open intervals is that there are so many uses of parentheses in math. I do prefer the "perverse" interval notation, but I'm using the `interval` package so as to have the option of reverting to non-perverse notation with a simple global change to the `intervalconfig` command's arguments for `left open fence` and `right open fence`.

Comment: @murray That's not a good excuse for using an ugly notation. 

Comment: The perverse notation will become standard in German schools 

Comment: @egreg: I don't find the use of outward-opening brackets for open intervals at all ugly (assuming the spacing is done properly), and no more ugly than the use of inward-opening brackets for closed intervals. But the particular typeface and symbol size used in Bourbaki does jar.