# Will TeXLive Utility update a package if I manually updated it?

Tags: packages, texlive, ctan

The `mismath` package v2.1 caused a conflict with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`. The problem is resolved with `mismath` v2.2.
(See: [mismath.sty bug?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670749/mismath-sty-bug))

The new version of `mismath` has been posted to CTAN but apparently has not precolated through to CTAN mirrors, because the TeXLive Utility (under macOS) is not yet finding it.

To remedy the immediate problem with the package, I therefore manually replaced `mismath.sty` in my local `texmf` tree (`/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex`...`).

**Question:** Once the new version of `mismath` is available on the CTAN mirrors, will the TeXLive Utility correctly pick up the new version and install it (including the `.ins`, `.dtx`, etc — which I did *not* manually replace)?

Note: I do realize that I can put the newer version in `~/Library/texmf` and then remove that once the TLU updates the one in `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex`.

Comment: no idea but why didn't you put the local version in your localtexmf or texmfhome tree (or into the folder of your document)??

Comment: Do you mean your local tree or your personal tree? In any case, yes, TLU will update the mismath package but the one you put in your `personal tree' will take precidence so you'll hafe to remove it. I beliefve there was an update to mismath today, 2023/01/07.

Comment: I just did an update with TexLive Utility that included an update to `mismath`. But it still seems to be the defective v 2.1 from late 2022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's just a problem of terminology:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/
```

is *not* the local tree, but the main one.

The *local* tree is at

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/
```

If you replace a single file in the main tree, then an update by `tlmgr` (or TeX Live Utility, which is just a front-end to it) will not care because it doesn't look at checksums or anything. Essentially, `tlmgr update` expands a compressed archive in the right place, after archiving the old version in the “backup area”; if the structure of the package is kept the same, no problem should arise (but the backup will be wrong). However, I don't recommand doing such replacement (see below).

It would be very different if you put the new version in the local tree or in the personal tree at `~/Library/texmf` (on macOS with MacTeX, it's `~/texmf` for TeX Live on other OSs); in either case you should create the path `[...]/tex/latex/mismath`) In the first case (local tree) you also need to run `mktexlsr` in order to update the lookup files; for the personal tree this is not needed.

In either case, the newly added file will take precedence over the one that's in the main tree and you need to remember pulling it away when the update is available with `tlmgr` (rerunning `mktexlsr` for the local tree case).

The order of precedence is always

1. the current working directory
2. the personal tree
3. the local tree
4. the main tree

so for a hotfix it's best to use the current directory. I recommend *not* replacing files in the main tree (although I've done some hotfix there in a few emergency cases to correct a spurious space). A file in the working directory is more easily spotted and removed. Using the personal tree would be better if you have several projects depending on this package sitting in different directories; in this case make a note to yourself

> ***Remember to remove `mismath.sty` from the personal tree***

##### Important note.

This is just for “simple” packages that consist of a single `.sty` file. Updating this way font packages, for instance, would be a little nightmare.

Comment: Yes, a matter of terminological confusion on my part. When I wrote "local" I was referring just to my own (single-user) computer.